# Setting a C# project to always compile in Release mode and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net

How do I set a single C# project to always build in either Release or Debug mode regardless of the solution target mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on the solution in the solution explorer.  Select "Configuration Manager".  Here, you can specify the project configurations used when the solution config is in 'Debug' or 'Release'.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Build Options, make the settings the same for Debug and Release. Specifically in Debug uncheck "Define DEBUG constant" and check "Optimize code"